# Sudden reboot of HP ProLiant DL 320 G5

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I recently suffer a sudden reboot of this server. I like to know why that happens. The only thing i see that happened just before reboot in the system.log is something about iLO. iLO is not connected, nor used at this time. And there is no other message about iLO in the logs.

Any idea ?

OS: Debian Etch

```
Dec 15 10:55:13 s01 snmpd[2717]: Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:59243
Dec 15 10:55:16 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: OsKcsExecCmd:  IPMI NetFN  0x36   CMD: 0x2 has timed out!
Dec 15 10:55:26 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: OsKcsExecCmd:  IPMI NetFN  0x36   CMD: 0x2 has timed out!
Dec 15 10:55:29 s01 snmpd[2717]: Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:59243
Dec 15 10:55:36 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: OsKcsExecCmd:  IPMI NetFN  0x36   CMD: 0x2 has timed out!
Dec 15 10:55:44 s01 snmpd[2717]: Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:59243
Dec 15 10:55:46 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: OsKcsExecCmd:  IPMI NetFN  0x36   CMD: 0x2 has timed out!
Dec 15 10:55:46 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: iLO 2 Communications Error - Attempting synchronization!
Dec 15 10:55:59 s01 snmpd[2717]: Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:59243
Dec 15 10:56:29 s01 last message repeated 2 times
Dec 15 10:56:31 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: iLO 2 has responded to reset request . . .
Dec 15 10:56:31 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: Stopping the Watchdog Timer . . .
Dec 15 10:56:31 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: Resetting Internal Data structures . . .
Dec 15 10:56:31 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: Initializing Internal Data structures from iLO 2. . .
Dec 15 10:56:31 s01 hpasmxld[4745]: The iLO 2 reset / synchronization has completed successfully
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the information here:

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=316587&prodTypeId=15351&objectID=c01330219

which seems to suggest that after an extended period of time of low server utilization, Automatic Server Recovery occurs.

Comment: Could be. I now deactivate ASR from System Management and observe.

Answer (score 3):

Since your machine has the HP management agents installed (based on the log entries), you can take a quick look at the HP Integrated Management Log to see if an ASR was actually recorded. Run `hplog -v` to display the log. A typical message indicating an ASR shutdown would look like:

```
0003 Critical       13:49  02/23/2010 13:49  02/23/2010 0001
LOG: ASR Detected by System ROM
```

You may also want to check your messages log. The HP management agents can output something like this following an ASR:

```
Trap-ID=6025
An 'ASR Recover Complete' trap signifies that the system has
been shutdown by the ASR feature and has just become operational
again.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar fault with an HP server which was down to over heating as a result of a badly fitted factory CPU heatsink.

The server itself showed no outward signs of there being an issue but in your case it might be worthwhile checking CPU temperatures and (during a period of planned maintenance) run a memory check.

Comment: Not the case. Temp. is ok from System Management console. Thanks anyway.